# Emulator for roku tv for test remote controll

Tags: emulation, roku

How can I install Roku TV to check the remote control?

I tried to search in the official documentation, but I didn't find anything
Is it possible to install Roku TV on a computer?

Answer (score 0):

As of now, there is no emulator available for Roku devices.